# sorting array in php by key in another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort multidimensional Array by Value (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multidimensional-array-by-value-2)

```
array(200) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["cat"]=>
    string(6) "Movies"
    ["name"]=>
    string(22) "Life.of.Pi.2012.DVDSCR"
    ["url"]=>
    string(62) "https://thepiratebay.se/torrent/8036528/Life.of.Pi.2012.DVDSCR"
    ["seed"]=>
    string(5) "33981"
    ["leech"]=>
    string(5) "18487"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["cat"]=>
    string(6) "Movies"
    ["name"]=>
    string(41) "Django Unchained 2012 DVDSCR X264 AAC-P2P"
    ["url"]=>
    string(81) "https://thepiratebay.se/torrent/7990804/Django_Unchained_2012_DVDSCR_X264_AAC-P2P"
    ["seed"]=>
    string(5) "34279"
    ["leech"]=>
    string(5) "12256"
  }
...
}
```

I have such an array as shown above, and I would like to sort this array by seed indicator.
How to achieve this in php?

Comment: ...in particular, most easily done with `usort()` as described in a couple of answers there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `usort()` like this.

```
usort($torrentList, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['seed'] - $b['seed'];
});
```

Where `$torrentList` is the the array you showed us above. Documentation can be found **[here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)**.

Comment: Congratulations, you beat me to the answer by 14 seconds. +1

Comment: I'm surprised I wasn't the one who was beaten, happens to me more often than not.

Comment: Cheers, it's easier than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

```
usort($the_array, function($a, $b) {
    return ($a['seed'] - $b['seed']);
});
```